# Set picked date to another datepicker with Materialize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I'm using Materialize to create an app with two datepickers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#outDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
  });


  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#returnDate').datepicker({
              format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
          });
        });
```

What i need to do is pass the selected date from datepicker 1 ('#outDate') and set into datepicker 2 ('#returnDate'). How can i do that. I've read the doc of Materialize, but i'm not getting any success.

Someone can help me, please?

Also i'm using Javascript and AngulrJs.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#outDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var date = $("#outDate").datepicker('getDate').getDate(); // get selected date of #outDate
            $('#returnDate').datepicker('defaultDate ', new Date(date)); // set #outDate date to #returnDate
        }
    });
  });


   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#returnDate').datepicker({
          format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      });
    });
```

Added working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wkkzytp9/12/)

Comment: Thanks, but now i'm getting an error: it says that getDate method doesn't exist on jQuery.datepicker

Comment: Sorry, again tested but still showing the same error :/

Comment: Ok. Which version of jquery date picker you are using?

Comment: Hey. I've noticed you use the method 'defaultDate' and not 'setDate'. could it be the reason? or at the very least, a workaround? I would write a full code but i'm using vailla JS, so that won't really help you..